# "Секонд хенд": в кавычках или без?

Tags: пунктуация

Часто в жизни пользуюсь этими магазинами и, соответственно, делюсь впечатлениями с друзьями. И всякий раз не знаю, как нужно писать само словосочетание "секонд хенд": в кавычках или без? Если это просто тип магазина, как универмаг или гипермаркет, тогда, по логике, без.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Секонд-хенд пишется без кавычек и через дефис. Это, действительно, тип магазина, вроде гастронома, универмага и т. д.

Comment: А точно через дефис? По-английски-то будет без дефиса — second hand

Comment: Ну, я видел и слитное написание, но эти продаваны такие грамотери: видел название магазина "Элипс" (именно с одним "л").

Comment: По английски и New York без дефиса, а в русском с дефисом - так адаптируются в русском англицизмы.

Comment: Да, полностью согласна с Инной. Поскольку в русском языке слова "секонд" и "хенд" отдельно не существуют (я, конечно, не имею в виду их перевод - речь идет именно об этих конкретных английских словах), то само понятие "секонд-хенд" наш язык адаптирует как единое. Отсюда и написание через дефис. Приведу еще один пример: во французском языке есть два предлога a la, которые всегда пишутся отдельно, русский язык их заимствовал как "а-ля" (через дефис), что означает "вроде кого-чего-нибудь.